# How does WiFiSLAM work?

Tags: geolocation, mobile, indoor, wifi

Apple recently acquired WifiSlam.  How does their technology work?

Their [website](https://angel.co/wifislam) doesn't go into much detail.

> Allow your smartphone to pinpoint its location (and the location of
>   your friends) in real-time to 2.5m accuracy using only ambient WiFi
>   signals that are already present in buildings.
>
> We are building the next generation of location-based mobile apps
>   that, for the first time, engage with users at the scale that personal
>   interaction actually takes place. Applications range from step-by-step
>   indoor navigation, to product-level retail customer engagement, to
>   proximity-based social networking.

Comment: your current location is logged. They have a database with access points locations (via mac addresses) and Trilateration  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration is used to approximate your inside location (x,y not z).

Answer (score 7):

After googling a bit more, I found this paper, [Using Wi-Fi for Navigating the Great Indoors](http://m.technologyreview.com/news/424213/using-wi-fi-for-navigating-the-great-indoors/).  I suppose the algorithm that handles multiple fingerprints, plus compass and accelerometer is what caught Apple's eye.

> When a gadget using WiFiSLAM wants to know its location, it analyzes
>   the signal strengths and unique IDs of all the Wi-Fi networks around
>   it. That is matched against a reference data set for the area either
>   accessed over the Internet, or stored on the device. The estimate of
>   location can be sharpened if a gadget moves slightly, because
>   WiFiSLAM's algorithms can gather multiple fingerprints. Compass data
>   and accelerometer signals capturing a person's footsteps are also used
>   to refine the accuracy of subsequent location fixes as a person moves
>   around.
>
> WiFiSLAM needs similar data to be gathered in advance inside a
>   particular building before it can offer location fixes. A person
>   running another special app must walk around a building a few times,
>   entering every room at least once. Algorithms originally developed for
>   robot navigation process the changing pattern of Wi-Fi fingerprints
>   and footsteps to re-create the path the person covered. That trace is
>   then manually associated with a map of the place so that WiFiSLAM can
>   tell a user in that environment where they are.

**Edit 2:** Also, looks like WifiSlam had [a blog that's been removed](http://www.wifislam.com/blog/2012/12/31/happy-new-year/).  However, Google still has [it in their cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Qfgzot-kzzIJ:www.wifislam.com/blog/2012/12/31/happy-new-year/%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) with some details:

> Most recently, WiFiSLAM’s inertial sensor fusion was featured in
>   [Grizzly Analytics](http://grizzlyanalytics.blogspot.com/2012/12/sensor-fusion-goes-solo-with-wifislam.html). It sparked some excellent e-mail discussion with
>   Dr. Bruce Krulwich and we’d love to summarize it for you here!
>
> - The demo video includes no maps constraints. It is purely accelerometer, gyroscope, and compass.
> - We are able to get better-than-typical accuracy because we are taking non-traditional pattern-matching approaches to sensor fusion
>     rather than the conventional “double-integration + Kalman filter”
>     techniques used traditionally.
> - We held the phone in front of us, trying to mimic a typical smartphone user who is following a map and walking while looking at
>     their phone. Nothing super-specific.
> - Inertial sensor fusion is now enabled by default as of last week’s releases of the entire WiFiSLAM product line: footprint.io, WiFiSLAM
>     QuickMap, and the Indoor Location SDK. Any user of WiFiSLAM with a
>     gyroscope-enabled smartphone will receive hybrid positioning that uses
>     both our Wi-Fi fingerprinting technology combined with our inertial
>     sensor fusion.

**Edit 3**  Grizzly analytics provides map setup details in [their recent blog post](http://grizzlyanalytics.blogspot.com/2013/03/apple-acquires-wifislam.html).

> WiFiSlam has released a mobile app that enables any smartphone user to
>   take a picture of a map of their indoor site, walk around the site a
>   few times, and have that site work within WiFiSLAM's location
>   positioning system.  This app enables much easier crowd-sourcing of
>   indoor maps than Google or others have, and would enable iPhone indoor
>   positioning to spread like wildfire as iPhone fanboys jump to upload
>   their site maps.

**Edit 4** Here's [a video from the GeoMeetup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGdvjvla1Tc) (kindly posted by [Ragi Burhum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1965/ragi-yaser-burhum)) where Joseph Huang of WiFiSLAM presents a talk about the underlying algorithms.

Comment: Kirk, This is a valid answer so undeleted, if you wanted it deleted again please comment on why.

Comment: @Mapperz I thought it was duplicating Bino's answer.  I've gone ahead and added more info to differentiate it, so I guess it should not be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

MIT technology review has this document
http://m.technologyreview.com/news/424213/using-wi-fi-for-navigating-the-great-indoors/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here at GIS SE though, we try to keep the answer self-contained. It would be great if you could put a summary of the article in your answer, or at least the pertinent parts of the article.

Answer (score 2):

Research on **Wifi-Trilateration**

Expanding on the comment
"your current location is logged. They have a database with access points locations (via mac addresses) and Trilateration  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration is used to approximate your inside location (x,y not z)."

Signal strength is an important factor working out the location of the wifi access point.

in this pdf it is explains the research into using wifi signal strength as well

> Wi-Fi Multilateration One method which is the focus of much research
>   is to use the signal strength receive d from Wi-Fi access points. The
>   advantages of using Wi-Fi networks are that they are becoming much
>   more common, and that the received signal strength is available as
>   part of the networking statistics available on the mobile device.
>   This means that specialist equipment is not required to provide
>   location information.

http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/lcs/previous/LCS2005/12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

http://cradioiisc.wordpress.com/

We are working on similar stuff and analyzing different algorithms.
The link above outlines few.

Comment: Thanks for posting!  Looks like some interesting research.  Does [Wi-Vi](http://people.csail.mit.edu/fadel/wivi/) use the same types of algorithms?